# Errors opening serial port in UWP app

Tags: c#, exception, serial-port, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to open a serial port in a Universal app following the instructions found in https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm

My app has the correct DeviceCapability in Package.appxmanifest and I can enumerate correctly all the devices and all of them are found when calling to:

```
var selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

The problem arise when I try to open any of the serial ports. The call to SerialDevice.FromIdAsync always returns null.

```
var serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);
```

Then, as explained in https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2015/3-81, I try to analyze the problem calling to DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceId and the surprise is that this call throws a FileNotFoundException.

The string I'm passing to DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceId is:

```
"\\?\ROOT#UBLOXVCP#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
```

but it also throws the exception with:

```
"\\?\ACPI#PNP0501#1#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
```

both of them throws the FileNotFoundException.

In the Channel 9 video, Arvind Aiyar says something like you can reboke the access to the serial ports with the Privacy configuration of Windows 10, but I can't found anything in relationship with Serial Ports in the Privacy configuration.

To test what's happening I tried to disassembly the DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceId method with dotPeek and no way to access to the WinRT part so I decided to call to a different API.

If you search {86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73} you'll see that it is the device interface class is defined for COM ports, so I called to:

```
DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClassId(new Guid("{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"));
```

and this method doesn't throws any exception and returns DeviceAccessStatus.Unspecified

I am using Windows 10 Pro x64 version 1511, compilation 10586.71, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is all about permissions?